# glibc upgrade error: gawk: error while loading shared libraries: /lib64/libm.so.6: invalid ELF header

Tags: glibc

I am trying to path [CVE-2015-7547](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=574880) which base on `glibc2.22`, everything is good but getting `make install` error

My linux version: `2.6.32.43`

Upgrade `glibc-2.12` to `glibc-2.22`

```
glibc-2.22> mkdir build
glibc-2.22/build> cat config.log 

    This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
    running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

    It was created by GNU C Library configure (see version.h), which was
    generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

      $ ../configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux --prefix=/usr

    ...
```

`make` is done

But `make install`:

```
...
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 bits/math-finite.h /usr/include/bits/math-finite.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../sysdeps/x86/fpu/bits/math-vector.h /usr/include/bits/math-vector.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../bits/libm-simd-decl-stubs.h /usr/include/bits/libm-simd-decl-stubs.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../sysdeps/ieee754/ieee754.h /usr/include/ieee754.h
(echo '/* GNU ld script'; echo '*/';\
         cat /home/xxxx/data/test/glibc-2.22/build/format.lds; \
         echo 'GROUP ( /lib64/libm.so.6 ' \
              'AS_NEEDED ( /lib64/libmvec.so.1 ) )' \
        ) > /usr/lib64/libm.so
/usr/bin/install -c /home/xxxx/data/test/glibc-2.22/build/math/libm.so /lib64/libm-2.22.so.new
mv -f /lib64/libm-2.22.so.new /lib64/libm-2.22.so
echo `../scripts/rellns-sh -p /lib64/libm-2.22.so /lib64/libm.so.6` /lib64/libm.so.6 >> /home/qspace/data/test/glibc-2.22/build/elf/symlink.list
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /home/xxxx/data/test/glibc-2.22/build/math/libieee.a /usr/lib64/libieee.a
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /home/xxxx/data/test/glibc-2.22/build/math/libm.a /usr/lib64/libm.a
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /home/xxxx/data/test/glibc-2.22/build/gnu/lib-names-64.h /usr/include/gnu/lib-names-64.h
(cd /home/xxxx/data/test/glibc-2.22/build/math/.; /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/objdump -h s_isinf.o s_isnan.o s_finite.o s_copysign.o s_modf.o s_scalbn.o s_frexp.o s_ldexp.o s_signbit.o s_isinff.o s_isnanf.o s_finitef.o s_copysignf.o s_modff.o s_scalbnf.o s_frexpf.o s_ldexpf.o s_signbitf.o s_isinfl.o s_isnanl.o s_finitel.o s_copysignl.o s_modfl.o s_scalbnl.o s_frexpl.o s_ldexpl.o s_signbitl.o setfpucw.o fpu_control.o s_isinf.os s_isnan.os s_finite.os s_copysign.os s_modf.os s_scalbn.os s_frexp.os s_ldexp.os s_signbit.os s_isinff.os s_isnanf.os s_finitef.os s_copysignf.os s_modff.os s_scalbnf.os s_frexpf.os s_ldexpf.os s_signbitf.os s_isinfl.os s_isnanl.os s_finitel.os s_copysignl.os s_modfl.os s_scalbnl.os s_frexpl.os s_ldexpl.os s_signbitl.os setfpucw.os fpu_control.os libieee.a ieee-math.o s_lib_version.o s_matherr.o s_signgam.o fclrexcpt.o fgetexcptflg.o fraiseexcpt.o fsetexcptflg.o ftestexcept.o fegetround.o fesetround.o fegetenv.o feholdexcpt.o fesetenv.o feupdateenv.o t_exp.o fedisblxcpt.o feenablxcpt.o fegetexcept.o powl_helper.o e_acos.o e_acosh.o e_asin.o e_atan2.o e_atanh.o e_cosh.o e_exp.o e_fmod.o e_hypot.o e_j0.o e_j1.o e_jn.o e_lgamma_r.o e_log.o e_log10.o e_pow.o e_rem_pio2.o e_remainder.o e_scalb.o e_sinh.o e_sqrt.o e_gamma_r.o e_ilogb.o k_cos.o k_rem_pio2.o k_sin.o k_tan.o s_asinh.o s_atan.o s_cbrt.o s_ceil.o s_cos.o s_erf.o s_expm1.o s_fabs.o s_floor.o s_log1p.o w_log1p.o s_logb.o s_nextafter.o s_nexttoward.o s_rint.o s_scalbln.o w_scalbln.o s_significand.o s_sin.o s_tan.o s_tanh.o w_acos.o w_acosh.o w_asin.o w_atan2.o w_atanh.o w_cosh.o w_drem.o w_exp.o w_exp2.o w_exp10.o w_fmod.o w_tgamma.o w_hypot.o w_j0.o w_j1.o w_jn.o w_lgamma.o w_lgamma_r.o w_log.o w_log10.o w_pow.o w_remainder.o w_scalb.o w_sinh.o w_sqrt.o w_ilogb.o s_fpclassify.o s_fmax.o s_fmin.o s_fdim.o s_nan.o s_trunc.o s_remquo.o e_log2.o e_exp2.o s_round.o s_nearbyint.o s_sincos.o conj.o cimag.o creal.o cabs.o carg.o s_cexp.o s_csinh.o s_ccosh.o s_clog.o s_catan.o s_casin.o s_ccos.o s_csin.o s_ctan.o s_ctanh.o s_cacos.o s_casinh.o s_cacosh.o s_catanh.o s_csqrt.o s_cpow.o s_cproj.o s_clog10.o s_fma.o s_lrint.o s_llrint.o s_lround.o s_llround.o e_exp10.o w_log2.o s_isinf_ns.o s_issignaling.o m_isinf.o m_isnan.o m_finite.o m_copysign.o m_modf.o m_scalbn.o m_frexp.o m_ldexp.o m_signbit.o x2y2m1.o k_casinh.o gamma_product.o k_standard.o e_acosf.o e_acoshf.o e_asinf.o e_atan2f.o e_atanhf.o e_coshf.o e_expf.o e_fmodf.o e_hypotf.o e_j0f.o e_j1f.o e_jnf.o e_lgammaf_r.o e_logf.o e_log10f.o e_powf.o e_rem_pio2f.o e_remainderf.o e_scalbf.o e_sinhf.o e_sqrtf.o e_gammaf_r.o e_ilogbf.o k_cosf.o k_rem_pio2f.o k_sinf.o k_tanf.o s_asinhf.o s_atanf.o s_cbrtf.o s_ceilf.o s_cosf.o s_erff.o s_expm1f.o s_fabsf.o s_floorf.o s_log1pf.o w_log1pf.o s_logbf.o s_nextafterf.o s_nexttowardf.o s_rintf.o s_scalblnf.o w_scalblnf.o s_significandf.o s_sinf.o s_tanf.o s_tanhf.o w_acosf.o w_acoshf.o w_asinf.o w_atan2f.o w_atanhf.o w_coshf.o w_dremf.o w_expf.o w_exp2f.o w_exp10f.o w_fmodf.o w_tgammaf.o w_hypotf.o w_j0f.o w_j1f.o w_jnf.o w_lgammaf.o w_lgammaf_r.o w_logf.o w_log10f.o w_powf.o w_remainderf.o w_scalbf.o w_sinhf.o w_sqrtf.o w_ilogbf.o s_fpclassifyf.o s_fmaxf.o s_fminf.o s_fdimf.o s_nanf.o s_truncf.o s_remquof.o e_log2f.o e_exp2f.o s_roundf.o s_nearbyintf.o s_sincosf.o conjf.o cimagf.o crealf.o cabsf.o cargf.o s_cexpf.o s_csinhf.o s_ccoshf.o s_clogf.o s_catanf.o s_casinf.o s_ccosf.o s_csinf.o s_ctanf.o s_ctanhf.o s_cacosf.o s_casinhf.o s_cacoshf.o s_catanhf.o s_csqrtf.o s_cpowf.o s_cprojf.o s_clog10f.o s_fmaf.o s_lrintf.o s_llrintf.o s_lroundf.o s_llroundf.o e_exp10f.o w_log2f.o s_isinf_nsf.o s_issignalingf.o m_isinff.o m_isnanf.o m_finitef.o m_copysignf.o m_modff.o m_scalbnf.o m_frexpf.o m_ldexpf.o m_signbitf.o x2y2m1f.o k_casinhf.o gamma_productf.o k_standardf.o e_acosl.o e_acoshl.o e_asinl.o e_atan2l.o e_atanhl.o e_coshl.o e_expl.o e_fmodl.o e_hypotl.o e_j0l.o e_j1l.o e_jnl.o e_lgammal_r.o e_logl.o e_log10l.o e_powl.o e_rem_pio2l.o e_remainderl.o e_scalbl.o e_sinhl.o e_sqrtl.o e_gammal_r.o e_ilogbl.o k_cosl.o k_rem_pio2l.o k_sinl.o k_tanl.o s_asinhl.o s_atanl.o s_cbrtl.o s_ceill.o s_cosl.o s_erfl.o s_expm1l.o s_fabsl.o s_floorl.o s_log1pl.o w_log1pl.o s_logbl.o s_nextafterl.o s_nexttowardl.o s_rintl.o s_scalblnl.o w_scalblnl.o s_significandl.o s_sinl.o s_tanl.o s_tanhl.o w_acosl.o w_acoshl.o w_asinl.o w_atan2l.o w_atanhl.o w_coshl.o w_dreml.o w_expl.o w_exp2l.o w_exp10l.o w_fmodl.o w_tgammal.o w_hypotl.o w_j0l.o w_j1l.o w_jnl.o w_lgammal.o w_lgammal_r.o w_logl.o w_log10l.o w_powl.o w_remainderl.o w_scalbl.o w_sinhl.o w_sqrtl.o w_ilogbl.o s_fpclassifyl.o s_fmaxl.o s_fminl.o s_fdiml.o s_nanl.o s_truncl.o s_remquol.o e_log2l.o e_exp2l.o s_roundl.o s_nearbyintl.o s_sincosl.o conjl.o cimagl.o creall.o cabsl.o cargl.o s_cexpl.o s_csinhl.o s_ccoshl.o s_clogl.o s_catanl.o s_casinl.o s_ccosl.o s_csinl.o s_ctanl.o s_ctanhl.o s_cacosl.o s_casinhl.o s_cacoshl.o s_catanhl.o s_csqrtl.o s_cpowl.o s_cprojl.o s_clog10l.o s_fmal.o s_lrintl.o s_llrintl.o s_lroundl.o s_llroundl.o e_exp10l.o w_log2l.o s_isinf_nsl.o s_issignalingl.o m_isinfl.o m_isnanl.o m_finitel.o m_copysignl.o m_modfl.o m_scalbnl.o m_frexpl.o m_ldexpl.o m_signbitl.o x2y2m1l.o k_casinhl.o gamma_productl.o k_standardl.o t_sincosl.o k_sincosl.o branred.o doasin.o dosincos.o halfulp.o mpa.o mpatan2.o mpatan.o mpexp.o mplog.o mpsqrt.o mptan.o sincos32.o slowexp.o slowpow.o sincostab.o s_floor-c.o s_ceil-c.o s_floorf-c.o s_ceilf-c.o s_rint-c.o s_rintf-c.o s_nearbyint-c.o s_nearbyintf-c.o e_exp-fma4.o e_log-fma4.o e_pow-fma4.o s_atan-fma4.o e_asin-fma4.o e_atan2-fma4.o s_sin-fma4.o s_tan-fma4.o mplog-fma4.o mpa-fma4.o slowexp-fma4.o slowpow-fma4.o sincos32-fma4.o doasin-fma4.o dosincos-fma4.o halfulp-fma4.o mpexp-fma4.o mpatan2-fma4.o mpatan-fma4.o mpsqrt-fma4.o mptan-fma4.o e_exp-avx.o e_log-avx.o s_atan-avx.o e_atan2-avx.o s_sin-avx.o s_tan-avx.o mplog-avx.o mpa-avx.o slowexp-avx.o mpexp-avx.o s_lib_version.os s_matherr.os s_signgam.os fclrexcpt.os fgetexcptflg.os fraiseexcpt.os fsetexcptflg.os ftestexcept.os fegetround.os fesetround.os fegetenv.os feholdexcpt.os fesetenv.os feupdateenv.os t_exp.os fedisblxcpt.os feenablxcpt.os fegetexcept.os powl_helper.os e_acos.os e_acosh.os e_asin.os e_atan2.os e_atanh.os e_cosh.os e_exp.os e_fmod.os e_hypot.os e_j0.os e_j1.os e_jn.os e_lgamma_r.os e_log.os e_log10.os e_pow.os e_rem_pio2.os e_remainder.os e_scalb.os e_sinh.os e_sqrt.os e_gamma_r.os e_ilogb.os k_cos.os k_rem_pio2.os k_sin.os k_tan.os s_asinh.os s_atan.os s_cbrt.os s_ceil.os s_cos.os s_erf.os s_expm1.os s_fabs.os s_floor.os s_log1p.os w_log1p.os s_logb.os s_nextafter.os s_nexttoward.os s_rint.os s_scalbln.os w_scalbln.os s_significand.os s_sin.os s_tan.os s_tanh.os w_acos.os w_acosh.os w_asin.os w_atan2.os w_atanh.os w_cosh.os w_drem.os w_exp.os w_exp2.os w_exp10.os w_fmod.os w_tgamma.os w_hypot.os w_j0.os w_j1.os w_jn.os w_lgamma.os w_lgamma_r.os w_log.os w_log10.os w_pow.os w_remainder.os w_scalb.os w_sinh.os w_sqrt.os w_ilogb.os s_fpclassify.os s_fmax.os s_fmin.os s_fdim.os s_nan.os s_trunc.os s_remquo.os e_log2.os e_exp2.os s_round.os s_nearbyint.os s_sincos.os conj.os cimag.os creal.os cabs.os carg.os s_cexp.os s_csinh.os s_ccosh.os s_clog.os s_catan.os s_casin.os s_ccos.os s_csin.os s_ctan.os s_ctanh.os s_cacos.os s_casinh.os s_cacosh.os s_catanh.os s_csqrt.os s_cpow.os s_cproj.os s_clog10.os s_fma.os s_lrint.os s_llrint.os s_lround.os s_llround.os e_exp10.os w_log2.os s_isinf_ns.os s_issignaling.os m_isinf.os m_isnan.os m_finite.os m_copysign.os m_modf.os m_scalbn.os m_frexp.os m_ldexp.os m_signbit.os x2y2m1.os k_casinh.os gamma_product.os k_standard.os e_acosf.os e_acoshf.os e_asinf.os e_atan2f.os e_atanhf.os e_coshf.os e_expf.os e_fmodf.os e_hypotf.os e_j0f.os e_j1f.os e_jnf.os e_lgammaf_r.os e_logf.os e_log10f.os e_powf.os e_rem_pio2f.os e_remainderf.os e_scalbf.os e_sinhf.os e_sqrtf.os e_gammaf_r.os e_ilogbf.os k_cosf.os k_rem_pio2f.os k_sinf.os k_tanf.os s_asinhf.os s_atanf.os s_cbrtf.os s_ceilf.os s_cosf.os s_erff.os s_expm1f.os s_fabsf.os s_floorf.os s_log1pf.os w_log1pf.os s_logbf.os s_nextafterf.os s_nexttowardf.os s_rintf.os s_scalblnf.os w_scalblnf.os s_significandf.os s_sinf.os s_tanf.os s_tanhf.os w_acosf.os w_acoshf.os w_asinf.os w_atan2f.os w_atanhf.os w_coshf.os w_dremf.os w_expf.os w_exp2f.os w_exp10f.os w_fmodf.os w_tgammaf.os w_hypotf.os w_j0f.os w_j1f.os w_jnf.os w_lgammaf.os w_lgammaf_r.os w_logf.os w_log10f.os w_powf.os w_remainderf.os w_scalbf.os w_sinhf.os w_sqrtf.os w_ilogbf.os s_fpclassifyf.os s_fmaxf.os s_fminf.os s_fdimf.os s_nanf.os s_truncf.os s_remquof.os e_log2f.os e_exp2f.os s_roundf.os s_nearbyintf.os s_sincosf.os conjf.os cimagf.os crealf.os cabsf.os cargf.os s_cexpf.os s_csinhf.os s_ccoshf.os s_clogf.os s_catanf.os s_casinf.os s_ccosf.os s_csinf.os s_ctanf.os s_ctanhf.os s_cacosf.os s_casinhf.os s_cacoshf.os s_catanhf.os s_csqrtf.os s_cpowf.os s_cprojf.os s_clog10f.os s_fmaf.os s_lrintf.os s_llrintf.os s_lroundf.os s_llroundf.os e_exp10f.os w_log2f.os s_isinf_nsf.os s_issignalingf.os m_isinff.os m_isnanf.os m_finitef.os m_copysignf.os m_modff.os m_scalbnf.os m_frexpf.os m_ldexpf.os m_signbitf.os x2y2m1f.os k_casinhf.os gamma_productf.os k_standardf.os e_acosl.os e_acoshl.os e_asinl.os e_atan2l.os e_atanhl.os e_coshl.os e_expl.os e_fmodl.os e_hypotl.os e_j0l.os e_j1l.os e_jnl.os e_lgammal_r.os e_logl.os e_log10l.os e_powl.os e_rem_pio2l.os e_remainderl.os e_scalbl.os e_sinhl.os e_sqrtl.os e_gammal_r.os e_ilogbl.os k_cosl.os k_rem_pio2l.os k_sinl.os k_tanl.os s_asinhl.os s_atanl.os s_cbrtl.os s_ceill.os s_cosl.os s_erfl.os s_expm1l.os s_fabsl.os s_floorl.os s_log1pl.os w_log1pl.os s_logbl.os s_nextafterl.os s_nexttowardl.os s_rintl.os s_scalblnl.os w_scalblnl.os s_significandl.os s_sinl.os s_tanl.os s_tanhl.os w_acosl.os w_acoshl.os w_asinl.os w_atan2l.os w_atanhl.os w_coshl.os w_dreml.os w_expl.os w_exp2l.os w_exp10l.os w_fmodl.os w_tgammal.os w_hypotl.os w_j0l.os w_j1l.os w_jnl.os w_lgammal.os w_lgammal_r.os w_logl.os w_log10l.os w_powl.os w_remainderl.os w_scalbl.os w_sinhl.os w_sqrtl.os w_ilogbl.os s_fpclassifyl.os s_fmaxl.os s_fminl.os s_fdiml.os s_nanl.os s_truncl.os s_remquol.os e_log2l.os e_exp2l.os s_roundl.os s_nearbyintl.os s_sincosl.os conjl.os cimagl.os creall.os cabsl.os cargl.os s_cexpl.os s_csinhl.os s_ccoshl.os s_clogl.os s_catanl.os s_casinl.os s_ccosl.os s_csinl.os s_ctanl.os s_ctanhl.os s_cacosl.os s_casinhl.os s_cacoshl.os s_catanhl.os s_csqrtl.os s_cpowl.os s_cprojl.os s_clog10l.os s_fmal.os s_lrintl.os s_llrintl.os s_lroundl.os s_llroundl.os e_exp10l.os w_log2l.os s_isinf_nsl.os s_issignalingl.os m_isinfl.os m_isnanl.os m_finitel.os m_copysignl.os m_modfl.os m_scalbnl.os m_frexpl.os m_ldexpl.os m_signbitl.os x2y2m1l.os k_casinhl.os gamma_productl.os k_standardl.os t_sincosl.os k_sincosl.os branred.os doasin.os dosincos.os halfulp.os mpa.os mpatan2.os mpatan.os mpexp.os mplog.os mpsqrt.os mptan.os sincos32.os slowexp.os slowpow.os sincostab.os s_floor-c.os s_ceil-c.os s_floorf-c.os s_ceilf-c.os s_rint-c.os s_rintf-c.os s_nearbyint-c.os s_nearbyintf-c.os e_exp-fma4.os e_log-fma4.os e_pow-fma4.os s_atan-fma4.os e_asin-fma4.os e_atan2-fma4.os s_sin-fma4.os s_tan-fma4.os mplog-fma4.os mpa-fma4.os slowexp-fma4.os slowpow-fma4.os sincos32-fma4.os doasin-fma4.os dosincos-fma4.os halfulp-fma4.os mpexp-fma4.os mpatan2-fma4.os mpatan-fma4.os mpsqrt-fma4.os mptan-fma4.os e_exp-avx.os e_log-avx.os s_atan-avx.os e_atan2-avx.os s_sin-avx.os s_tan-avx.os mplog-avx.os mpa-avx.os slowexp-avx.os mpexp-avx.os) | \
        gawk '/\.gnu\.glibc-stub\./ { \
                  sub(/\.gnu\.glibc-stub\./, "", $2); \
                  stubs[$2] = 1; } \
                END { for (s in stubs) print "#define __stub_" s }' > /home/xxxx/data/test/glibc-2.22/build/math/stubsT
gawk: error while loading shared libraries: /lib64/libm.so.6: invalid ELF header
make[2]: *** [/home/xxxx/data/test/glibc-2.22/build/math/stubs] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/data/xxxx/data/test/glibc-2.22/math'
make[1]: *** [math/subdir_install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/data/xxxx/data/test/glibc-2.22'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

and the old `/lib64/libm-2.12.so` content was changed and wrong.

```
/home/xxxx/data/test/glibc-2.22/build> cat /lib64/libm-2.12.so
/* GNU ld script
*/
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( /lib64/libm.so.6  AS_NEEDED ( /lib64/libmvec.so.1 ) )
/home/xxxx/data/test/glibc-2.22/build>
```

The cause of this error seems to be the old `libm-2.12`. So changed it and the new not set property, which step went wrong?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. I have my own Linux build and package management system, which is probably unusual. However, essentially my glibc package process is similar to building from source and then installing. I can build a new patched glibc at the same version number without any issues at all. The package system upgrade results in overwriting the original files without removing them first, since the package manifests are identical. All I need to do is restart init. I also reboot as well. My scenario for creating a new glibc package is specific to my situation though, so I won't go into details. This is how I handled CVE-2015-7547.

Updating glibc when the version number changes is more difficult. You should try installing with DESTDIR in the install targets, like this:

```
make DESTDIR=/tmp/stage install
```

There are more steps of course. Once you have glibc installed in a staging directory, you need to replace your current glibc files with the new ones properly. You need to do this without ripping out the old glibc files first. I was able to do this by hand for testing purposes by creating my own tar archive of the files in the staging directory. Exactly how to do this is beyond the scope of my answer right now, but I thought I would mention using DESTDIR like this. I am working on exact instructions for doing this on my system, but those would be specific to me in some respects. More information about DESTDIR can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html).

Comment: It works. run `make DESTDIR=/tmp/stage install`, then run `make install`.